# How can I freeze / constraint a PhysicsBody's rotation in Unity DOTS?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-dots, unity-ecs

I was trying to port a small test project from Unity Engine to learn about Unity New Fishers DOTS && ECS.

It's a small project where I have a capsule with a `Rigidbody` and I move it from left to right using add force and I clamp the velocity to limit the speed.

I'm trying to "Freeze Specific Rotations" on DOTS.

Without DOTS there is Unity's "normal" way to constraint a `Rigidbody` position and rotation.

[image]

But if we use DOTS I can't use `Rigidbody` since DOTS uses `PhysicsBody` and there I didn't find any way to freeze / constraint certain rotations.

How can I constraint a `PhysicsBody`'s rotation in DOTS?

Comment: Seemingly the answer to that is using `Joints` see e.g. [this thread](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1752736/adding-constraints-to-physicsbody-of-the-unityphys.html) ... in general you will find a lot more results when looking for `constraint` instead of `freeze` .. try searching `Unity DOTS constraint PhysicsBody` though to be fair: There seems to exist not much in that direction

Answer (score 3):

I was researching the answer to the same problem and managed to to find this on a unity forum.

[TRS6123's answer from a Unity Forum](https://forum.unity.com/threads/best-approach-to-lock-angular-axes-x-and-z-on-physics-entities.757196/#post-5049470)

Below the "Advanced" property of the physics body, you can check "Override Default Mass". When checked you can override the float3 value "Inertia Tensor". Setting one axis component to "Infinity" locks the rotation along that axis.

I did what he instructed and it is working like a charm for me right now.

[image: Visual Aid]

Comment: When possible, please put the actual answer on stack overflow directly instead of linking to it. This prevents link rot and similar problems and makes reading the answer more convenient. Linking to an image is specially problematic as one cannot copy the text and it has terrible accessibility.